# How to select the next minor id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

this is the js script that invokes ajax

```
var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0; 
$(document).scroll(function(){ 

currentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(); 

var ids = new Array();

if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop ) 
{
    var result = currentScrollTop % 100;
    if(result == 0 || (result > 20 && result < 30))
    {
        var items = $(".item");
        var items_l = items.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < items_l; i++)
        {
            ids[i] = parseInt(items[i].id.replace(/\D+/g,""));

        }
        ids = ids.sort();

        var last_id = ids[0];
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajax/load",
          type: "POST",
          data: {last_id : last_id},
          success: function(res){

          $("#content").append(res);

          }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the controller method

```
public function ajaxLoad()
{
    $last_id = intval($this->input->post("last_id"));
    //$last_id++;
    $db_data['query'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id < ".$last_id." LIMIT 1");
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('item', $db_data, true);
    echo $data['content'];
}
```

so the purpose is that i want to get the id in mysql that is minor that the current minor id of the page, for example if the minor id in the page is 25, i want to select the next N record, but if i write select all from items where id < current_id, the database selects the first row everytime, because is the most minor in all database, but i need the NEXT minor, how can this be done?

i mean that 20 is the next minor than 25, but i dont want to select 15, before i get 20

lets suppose that we have this ids in db: 14, 26 , 30 , 40...

so the minor in the page is 30, and i want to select the next minor id, it will be 26, and then 14, can this be possible to done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$db_data['query'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id < ".$last_id." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: @yeahitsme Glad to hear it. Don't forget to accept this answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @yeahitsme looks like you have 21 rep now :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need an `order by`:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id < $last_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

(I initially read this wrong and thought you were looking for higher numbers).

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string won't be necessary here because he used intval to convert last_id into an integer.

Comment: oh yeah, but is a post input that comes from ajax, how it can be hacked?? o_O, thanks yeah it works, thanks thanks!!!

Comment: @yeahitsme - It's safe in this case, like Basti said, since you're converting it to an integer. Keep in mind that (1) AJAX calls are just normal HTTP requests, so someone could make one manually and (2) JavaScript is easily changed, so even if they weren't, an attacker could change the JavaScript on their machine before running it.

Comment: ok , thanks for advice , i will keep in mind it, i have another problem, is that when i scroll the page down, it makes double requests, and get 2 equal records, maybe i need to change it to synchrous instead of asynchrous??